# Regex for matching decimals only, not integers

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to match decimal numbers only, but to fail on integers.

For example, the following numbers should pass

```
0.00
1.00
-1.00
3.3
2.22123
```

But the following should fail

```
-1
-3
4
559
```

I don't know why this is so hard to find/create, but I'm not having any luck. All available regexes that I found online don't exclude integers.

Comment: Maybe: `^-?\d+\.\d+$`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: You closed the question and added a related to a question that specifically asks for something else (matching floating point numbers AND integers, whereas my question wants to exclude integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern works [regexr.com/4ulml](https://regexr.com/4ulml)

```
^[-]?\d+\.\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d+\.\d+?$`
this pattern should work